# How to hide some of the classes and methods from Javadocs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I am  working on some Library project. I want to launch the Javadocs for the same, but I want to hide some of the classes from Javadocs. I did like as below:

```
/**
 * @hide
 * blah blah
 */
public class Blah  implements
        BlahInterface { 
}
```

When I am generating Javadocs of this then Android Studio is giving an error message that. I read this from here https://code.google.com/p/doclava/wiki/JavadocTags

> Unknown hide tag.

Please suggest how to hide class from Javadocs using Android Studio.

Comment: In addition to Andreas comment, there is a purpose tag called @exclude, but it does not currently exist.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/proposed-tags-142378.html

Answer (score 2):

That's an extension implemented by "Doclava". Android Studio doesn't understand Doclava. Doclava added that extension tag because Javadoc doesn't have it.

You can however instruct the `javadoc` command-line to exclude entire packages from Javadoc generation using the `-exclude` argument.

I don't think Android Studio can be told about such excludes, so it won't apply to source code javadocs, but it will apply to anyone using your generated Jar and Javadoc in another Android Studio project.